# powershell full drive path get ps-drive

Tags: powershell

I need to get the absolute path for the Y drive.
When i use Get-PSDrive, it truncates the full path.

I piped it out to a out-file and the file path is truncated as well.
How can I get the full path name.

```
PS F:\powershell> Get-PSDrive Y
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                                                  
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                                               
Y                  58.90         40.65 FileSystem    \\intranet.fooint.com\tan-FOO...
PS F:\powershell>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `| format-table -AutoSize` at the end as following:

```
Get-PSDrive "Y" | format-table -AutoSize
```

By default that command returns in  table view. By adding autosize it will try to size the column to a width that is appropriate to display all the information.  Also you will want to note that the output may show the root being cut off but the information is still retained. For example if you do the following:

```
$NetworkDrive = Get-PSDrive Y
$NetworkDrive.root
```

You will notice that `$NetworkDrive` still contains the full path even if it does not show it.